# Using Django CBV's without overriding get_context_data

Tags: python, django

Is there anyway I can take advantage of Django's default CBV's without resulting to super calls on the get_context_data to send extra pieces of info.

For instance, I have a site where the CBV's handle 99% of the work on their own, but I'd like to send minor bits of static info such as page titles and it seems unnecessary to use get_context_data just to accomplish this.

I'm aware that I can do the following:

```
class Page(DetailView):
  model: MyModel
  template_name: 'something.html'
  title: 'Some Page Title'
```

And reference title in my template as `view.title`. However I'd like the page title to be an attribute of my model. Which I'm able to do through the following:

```
get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
   context = super(Page, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
   context['title'] = 'Page Title | %s' % (self.get_object().title)

   return context
```

Is it possible for me to reference the individual model being called in the detail view without running a query or using get_context_data so I can get the model's title attribute and use access it as `view.title` in my template?

Comment: I am not sure what do you want but maybe this `Page Title | {{ object.title }}`

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any reason to define this method just to get the title. The whole point of a DetailView is that you have access to the object in the template, via `{{ object }}`. So why not just do `{{ object.title }}`?

Comment: There are other views which all share the same layout template and will have something different than `{{ object.title }}`, so I'd like to be able store all titles in `view.title` so I can do out put it with a single if statement: `{% if view.title %}`...

Comment: Well, then I'm afraid I don't really understand what you're asking. Either you use the data that's already provided by the generic views, or you define `get_context_data` to provide your own data.

Comment: And you specifically asked how to access an attribute of your model, so I'm even more confused.